# Can network VLAN be identified by a string rather than a number?

Tags: networking, vlan

Can VLAN be identified by a string rather than a number?

My wifi router allows to configure VLAN that are named by string.
I'm trying to connected it to my Ubiquiti EdgeRouter but can't get it to work. See bellow what settings I can change:

[Wifi router VLAN setup page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKKSz.png)

Comment: From your picture it looks as if you've got the default VLAN 1 (untagged) and VLAN 20 and 30. If would be rally weird if your router calls something "VLAN30" and would NOT use the VLAN-ID 30 for that VLAN.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The VLAN tag in an Ethernet packet is a 12 bit interger, providing 4096 numbered values. There is no string identification in the packet.

Since management of VLANs via numbers only is a burden on human memory and thus error-prone, vendors have soon started to allow associating a descriptive name with the numerical tags to ease that burden - but these names are local either to each device or in the best case to a family of devices that share a configuration database. AFAIK there is no cross-vendor way to synchronize name-number tuples.

In order to get this to work cleanly, you would need to set up **identical** name-number mappings on both devices manually, then things should work as expected.

Comment: Is there a way to detect the VLAN tag number coming from an interface?

Comment: @Pat You need to capture a (small) sample of the traffic with WireShark or similar software. This will show you what really is send across the line, including the VLAN tags. As soon as you know the VLAN number your router sends out you can create the appropriate VLAN in the EdgeRouter.